# Storing DB credentials for Java Jar file running on AWS EMR

Tags: java, mongodb, hadoop, amazon-web-services, emr

We are developing an hadoop application using Java that will run on AWS EMR. The application will use the [Mongo Hadoop connector](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/hadoop/) to connect to MongoDB to retrieve the input dataset. Once processing it complete the results will be written back to MongoDB.

We are having trouble trying to find best solution to store Mongo DB credentials so that Jar file can use them.

- We cant store the DB credentials in a properties file directly on the
  hadoop servers as we are using AWS EMR and a cluster will be created
  on a scheduled basis to run a job and then terminated - our cluster will not be running 24/7. Also it does not appear that we can create a customized version of the hadoop AMI and then have AWS EMR use our custom AMI to create a cluster (please let me know if this is possible?)
- The Jar file will sit on S3 so we don't like the idea of storing the
  password in a properties file embedded within the jar. Access to the
  S3 bucket will be restricted with IAM roles but it still doesn't really seam like a secure way to storing the credentials with the jar just sitting on S3?
- We've tried to pass properties to the Java runtime or set application
  variables in bash scripts that are run as bootstrap actions when the
  EMR cluster is created but the parameters passed to the bootstrap
  actions as logged in the EMR console and so would be visible to
  anyone with access to the console

Is there another approach that we have not considered or do we just have to accept that storing the jar file on S3 in a bucket with restricted access is the only viable solution?

Comment: could you solve this? I have the same problem.

Comment: no have not found a great solution yet - looks like we'll have to go with option 2 above and just ensure that the permissions on the S3 bucket where the JAR is stored are very locked down. If you can find a viable solution please let me know.